# Swap two colors using color matrix

Tags: c++, windows, colors, colormatrix

How can I swap two colors using a color matrix? For instance swapping red and blue is easy. The matrix would look like:

```
0 0 1 0 0
0 1 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 1
```

So how can I swap any two colors in general?  For example, there is Color1 with R1, G1, B1 and Color2 with R2, G2, B2.

EDIT: By swap I mean Color1 will translate into color2 and color2 will translate into color1. Looks like I need a reflection transformation. How to calculate it?

GIMP reference removed. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: Can you look at the gimp source code? That might be a lot of work for your answer but it is available: http://www.gimp.org/downloads/#mirrors

Comment: Using a color swapping matrix is for swapping values within a color, not swapping two separate colors...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by creating a reflection matrix via `D3DXMatrixReflect` using a plane that's perpendicular to the vector AB and intersects the midpoint of the AB.

1. `D3DXVECTOR3 AB( colorA.r-colorB.r, colorA.g-colorB.g, colorA.b-colorB.b );`
2. `D3DXPLANE plane( AB.x, AB.y, AB.z, -AB.x*midpoint.x-AB.y*midpoint.y-AB.z*midpoint.z );`
3. `D3DXMatrixReflect`

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be the section of the color-exchange.c file in the GIMP source that cycles through all the pixels and if a pixel meets the chosen criteria(which can be a range of colors), swaps it with the chosen color:

```
  for (y = y1; y < y2; y++)
    {
      gimp_pixel_rgn_get_row (&srcPR, src_row, x1, y, width);

      for (x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
          guchar pixel_red, pixel_green, pixel_blue;
          guchar new_red, new_green, new_blue;
          guint  idx;

          /* get current pixel-values */
          pixel_red   = src_row[x * bpp];
          pixel_green = src_row[x * bpp + 1];
          pixel_blue  = src_row[x * bpp + 2];

          idx = x * bpp;

          /* want this pixel? */
          if (pixel_red >= min_red &&
              pixel_red <= max_red &&
              pixel_green >= min_green &&
              pixel_green <= max_green &&
              pixel_blue >= min_blue &&
              pixel_blue <= max_blue)
            {
              guchar red_delta, green_delta, blue_delta;

              red_delta   = pixel_red > from_red ?
                pixel_red - from_red : from_red - pixel_red;
              green_delta = pixel_green > from_green ?
                pixel_green - from_green : from_green - pixel_green;
              blue_delta  = pixel_blue > from_blue ?
                pixel_blue - from_blue : from_blue - pixel_blue;

              new_red   = CLAMP (to_red   + red_delta,   0, 255);
              new_green = CLAMP (to_green + green_delta, 0, 255);
              new_blue  = CLAMP (to_blue  + blue_delta,  0, 255);
            }
          else
            {
              new_red   = pixel_red;
              new_green = pixel_green;
              new_blue  = pixel_blue;
            }

          /* fill buffer */
          dest_row[idx + 0] = new_red;
          dest_row[idx + 1] = new_green;
          dest_row[idx + 2] = new_blue;

          /* copy alpha-channel */
          if (has_alpha)
            dest_row[idx + 3] = src_row[x * bpp + 3];
        }
      /* store the dest */
      gimp_pixel_rgn_set_row (&destPR, dest_row, x1, y, width);

      /* and tell the user what we're doing */
      if (!preview && (y % 10) == 0)
        gimp_progress_update ((gdouble) y / (gdouble) height);
    }
```

[image: GIMP_Image]

**EDIT/ADDITION**

Another way you could have transformed red to blue would be with this matrix:

```
1   0   0   0   0
0   1   0   0   0
0   0   1   0   0
0   0   0   1   0
-1  0   1   0   1
```

The only values that really matter are the bottom ones in this matrix.

This would be the same as saying subtract 255 from red, keep green the same, and then add 255 to blue. You could cut the alpha in half like so as well like so:

```
-1  0   1   -0.5    1
```

So (just like the gimp source) you just need to find the difference between your current color and your target color, for each channel, and then apply the difference. Instead of channel values from 0 to 255 you would use values from 0 to 1.

You could have changed it from red to green like so:

```
-1  1   0   0   1
```

See here for some good info:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms533875%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Good luck.

Comment: I appreciate your help, I was just looking at the same code. This doesn't appear to be done via color matrix though and that is what I need.

Comment: @Vt Seems like color matrices are used for much more complicated operations than just swapping colors. (like rotating colors, scaling colors etc.) So that is what all that extra matrix info is for. But as far as what you are trying to do you only need to worry about the bottom row(assuming the standard top 4 rows in my example and the standard 5th column).

Comment: "Another way you could have transformed red to blue" - yes, with this matrix the red would become blue, but the blue wouldn't become red. That's my problem. I just realized that's not similar to GIMP then. Sad..

Comment: @Vt Yea you might want to try again with a new question - without the GIMP reference.